# Chrome remote desktop on macOS attempts to grant "accessibility" permissions to /bin/sh

Tags: macos, google-chrome, accessibility, macos-catalina, chrome-remote-desktop

The [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/) client for MacOs requires accessibility permissions be granted to "org.chromium.chromoting.me2me.sh" (which makes sense).

Ever since upgrading to Catalina, the "org.chromium.chromoting.me2me.sh" entry under "Settings -> Security and Privacy -> Accessibility" has been replaced with simply "sh", which points to /bin/sh!

I imagine granting Accessibility permission to /bin/sh is quite dangerous, but I can't seem to add "org.chromium.chromoting.me2me.sh" to the list. It's impossible to select it from the drive by clicking the "+" sign (see below). Removing "sh" via the minus sign, removing the Chrome remote desktop host and reinstalling only made "sh" reappear.

Needless to say, Chrome remote desktop does not work without these permissions. Any ideas how to restore the correct settings here?

[image: MacOS Catalina Security and Privacy Settings Window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was finally fixed in version 80.0.3987.87

Answer (score 0):

Fixing  was covered in Chromium bug [1013692](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1013692).

As of Dec 2019 the fix [hasn't](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1012550#c6) been rolled out yet though.